# Hibernate Cache with JPA does not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-cache

I use a cache of the second level with the entity manager Hibernate together. With objects that have small investment - ok.
But if the object has a large attachment of other objects, logs queries Hibernate main essence repeated several times:

```
    ....from
2017-01-23 12:04:20,528 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         doc_contract contract0_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,529 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     inner join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,529 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         doc_abstract_document contract0_1_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,529 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.entry_id=contract0_1_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,529 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_organization organizati1_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.org_entry_id=organizati1_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_organization organizati2_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on organizati1_.parent_id=organizati2_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor_account contractor3_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.account_entry_id=contractor3_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_bank bank4_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contractor3_.bank_entry_id=bank4_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor contractor5_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contractor3_.contractor_entry_id=contractor5_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor contractor6_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,567 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.contractor_entry_id=contractor6_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,567 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     where
2017-01-23 12:04:20,567 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         contract0_.entry_id=?

.... from
2017-01-23 12:04:20,772 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         doc_contract contract0_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,772 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     inner join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         doc_abstract_document contract0_1_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.entry_id=contract0_1_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_organization organizati1_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.org_entry_id=organizati1_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,774 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,774 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_organization organizati2_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,774 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on organizati1_.parent_id=organizati2_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,774 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,774 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor_account contractor3_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,780 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.account_entry_id=contractor3_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,780 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,780 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_bank bank4_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,780 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contractor3_.bank_entry_id=bank4_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,781 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,781 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor contractor5_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,781 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contractor3_.contractor_entry_id=contractor5_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,781 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     left outer join
2017-01-23 12:04:20,788 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         dict_contractor contractor6_ 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,788 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)             on contract0_.contractor_entry_id=contractor6_.entry_id 
2017-01-23 12:04:20,789 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)     where
2017-01-23 12:04:20,789 INFO  [stdout] (default task-38)         contract0_.entry_id=?
```

Main entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "doc_contract")
@Cacheable(true)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CUST_SEQ", sequenceName = "DOC_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class Contract extends AbstractSignedDocument implements Cloneable {
```

persistence.xml file:

```
    <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />

         <!--Кеш второго уровня-->
          <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.infisnisspan.cachemanager" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate"/>
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>

          <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor.session_scoped" value="ru.fsgp.pfhdn.service.DBInterceptor"/>

          <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>

      </properties>
```

Can anyone suggest why this might be? Thanks

Comment: We can't see the code you used to generate the logs, or which ids were bound to the query. It looks like it is configured to use Infinispan, is there some management tool which allows you to see what it is currently in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It helped
`<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>` 
My answer body code

Comment: It enable cache in all entities. I returned ENABLE_SELECTIVE. 
Help need